# How Can I Query a Specific Page From a MultiPage paginated Post

Tags: posts, query

Let's say I have a post that has been paginated by adding the

```
 <!-- nextpage -->
```

code provided by wordpress for this purpose.  How can I then query a specific page from inside of that post.  Say for instance I only want to query the contents of page 2 and there are 10 posts.  Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WordPress uses the PHP explode function to split the content into a
>   array of 'pages'. Happens in the setup_postdata function with this
>   code:
>
> $pages = explode('', $content);

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703099/how-does-wordpress-nextpage-tag-actually-work)

So you could do something like :

```
function wpse_103026( $content, $pagenum ) {
  if ( strpos( $content, '<!--nextpage-->' ) ) {
    $pages = explode('<!--nextpage-->', $content); 
    return isset ( $pages[$pagenum-1] ) ? trim( $pages[$pagenum-1] ) : $content;
    } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And then you can retrieve content of page 4 with :

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wpse_103026( $post->post_content, 4 ) );
```